# PLSQL stored procedure works different when called from PLSQL Developer or Java application

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, forall

In Oracle 11g (11.2.0.1.0, 64bit) database, I have a porcedure ( part of a package ) which uses FORALL to update a table.
The FORALL is in a dynamic SQL part, executed with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

When I call the procedure from PLSQL Developer the result is fine, the table update-ed as expected.

When the procedure called by a Java application ( using JDBCTemplate.execute(...), JDBC thin client ) then FORALL update fails randomly.
Not all the record updated in the table that should be updated only part of them. The not updated record set changes randomly from trial to trial.

The code is rather complex to quote here.
First I would like to know if there is any special thing, condition to check in case of Java call. Anyway, what technique and how to use properly when calling an Oracle stored procedure from Java.
The Java part not developed by me. I suspect that there is some issue with that code. How else can be that the PLSQL part works fine in standalone mode but fails with Java app.

Thank you for any comment and tips.

Comment: When you test it in PL/SQL Developer are you using the same data set as when the Java app runs it?

Comment: Are you using the same user? Exactly how do you execute it when it works, and how do you execute it when it doesn't?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no difference in running on a PLSQL Developer session and a JDBC thin client and I work with both in the last 13 years =). The difference in behavior may be related to a different user connected, session parameters like NLS_LANG or some changes in data done before in the same transaction (if it is the case). If everything is equal in both sessions the behavior will be the same.

Comment: @APC Yes, I am using the same data set in both cases.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, Yes,same user logs in when Java app runs and when PLSQL Developer test runs.

Comment: @czdepski The users are same in both cases. Some of the sys_context userenv parameters are different: HOST, IP_ADDRESS, LANG, LANGUAGE, MODULE, NLS_CURRENCY, NLS_DATE_FORMAT, NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE, NLS_SORT, NLS_TERRITORY, OS_USER, SESSIONID, SID, TERMINAL.

Comment: From the sys_context() differences it seems it's two different environments. How do you know that the data is the same in both instances?

Comment: @czdepski  In the FORALL UPDATE statement, the record selection for update is done by ID column comparision ( sg. like this:  WHERE ID = v_record(k).ID )  where ID is number data type containing only integers. So, different NLS parameters should not be problem, I think.

Comment: @APC There is only one database. The same tables are used. From which parameter you see that there are two instances ?  Sorry, I am not familiar with this instance thing.

Comment: @GarryS.C. 
He used word 'instance' not as a 'database instance', but rather 'times when you run your script' :)

Trace, how many records you have in your v_record table before you do forall update.
The problem might lay in what you fetch to the collection in the first place.